# Changing sequence type during training SimpleRNN in python/keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on a project where we use Simple RNN and LSTM network to compare the results of ARIMA forecast method.We use electricity price data for 9 years to train networks. We want some comparable models for RNN and ARIMA forecast method. In ARIMA method, some past time data being used where some not. For example we use X(t-1), X(t-2), X(t-24), X(t-48) and X(t-168) to predict X[t:t+23]. To compare the Simple RNN and ARIMA method, we need to manipulate the network model where input sequence size is 5 and output size is 24.

Is it possible?